# Threshold on old space in ParallelOldGC Garbage Collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

I am using `ParallelOldGC` as garbage collector in my application.The max heap size is set as 2 GB and working on Java hot spot 6, 27 update.

My application create so many long life objects due to which old space got full. So as per the parallel GC algorithm , Full GC trigger when the old space is almost full.As the heap size is 2 GB so to clean the old space the collector take more than 100 seconds which is not acceptable.

I am thinking to set threshold on old space say 30 so that when old space completed with 30% then Full GC will be called , as this solution will increase the FullGC count but it will decrease the application pause time.

I have observed that CMS contain such facility with `XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction` but due to some drawback of CMS cant switch to CMS.So is there any facility to set in ParallelOldGC

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> As the heap size is 2 GB so to clean the old space the collector take more than 100 seconds which is not acceptable.

Since what you're actually trying to solve is long pause times you can set a pause time goal via `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=` and the collector will *try* to meet that.

It may fail for various reasons to meet it, e.g. because it's not allowed to burn enough CPU time on collecting (via `GCTimeRatio`) or simply because that you have so many old, live objects that the goal cannot be met (use G1 or CMS in those cases).